# Insert values from a ListManager Oracle Apex

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, procedure

I have a table Aux_Nac which is represented on the form Students by a List Manager item. Their connection: **Students** -|-----< [**Aux_Nac**] >------|- **Nationalities**. I know that PXX_LISTMANAGER has something ike this saved: 'A:B:C:D:Z:P:Y', but **how do I take it out and record it**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **create a procedure** which **Point is Processing** and Server side condition Type is Request is contained in Value, below write CREATE
2. Alter this code and copy it and past in the procedure's code:

   ```
   DECLARE
      l_nat nationalities.nome%type;
      l_remainings varchar2(500);
      l_pos number := 0;
   BEGIN
     l_remainings := :P27_nationalities || ':';
     WHILE INSTR(l_remainings, ':') > 0
     LOOP
       l_pos := INSTR(l_remainings, ':');
       l_nat := SUBSTR(l_remainings, 0, l_pos - 1);
       l_remainings := SUBSTR(l_remainings, l_pos + 1, LENGTH(l_remainings));
       INSERT INTO AUX_NAC (nationalities_id
                           ,students_id)
       VALUES ((SELECT nc.id_nc FROM nationalities nc WHERE nc.name = l_nat)
              ,:P27_ID);
     END LOOP;
   ```

   END;